# Second order boundary value problem system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

Let $A$ be $n \times n$ real matrix and consider the following boundary value problem system
$$y''(x)=Ay(x) \\ y(0)=y(1)=0,$$
where 0 is the null vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The matrix $A$ is not necessarely diagonalizable.
How can we solve this system explicitly? Is there any references about that?. Thank you.